# The output of c language mpi program differ with number of processes

Tags: c, mpi

I need to write down a parallel code for this formula

[image]

I wrote a mpi program in c language for parallel programming

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<mpi.h>
double sum(int n);

int main(void){

    int my_rank,comm_sz, n=1;
    double local_sum, total_sum;
    int source;
    int local_n;

MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);


local_n= n/comm_sz;
local_sum=sum(local_n);



if ( my_rank != 0) {
     MPI_Send (&local_sum , 1, MPI_DOUBLE , 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD ) ;
 }

 else{
     total_sum = local_sum;
     for(source=1;source<comm_sz;source++){
     MPI_Recv (&local_sum , 1, MPI_DOUBLE , source , 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE ) ;
     total_sum+=local_sum;
    }
  }
if(my_rank==0){
     printf("Sum is=%lf",total_sum);
     printf("\n");
}
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}


double sum(int n){
int i;
double cal_sum=0;
for (i =0;i <= n;i++) {
cal_sum = cal_sum + 4*(pow (-1, i))/((2*i)+1);
}
return cal_sum;
}
```

The output should be same whatever the number of process is. But as per my code when I run the program for 1 process the result is different than the number of process 8.

For example, if n= 1, p= 1 the summation is 2.667

```
 Whereas, if n= 1, p= 8 the summation is 32.00
```

But as per my understanding even if p= 8 the result of summation should be 2.667

Comment: manually run your program with `p=2` and see how it goes.

Comment: if p =2  Answer: 8.00000. Why are you asking for p=2?

Comment: so you have established your program gives an incorrect error with 2 and 8 processes. I think it is easier to manually run/debug with 2 MPI tasks rather than 8. Makes sense?

Comment: All your processes are computing the same number.

Comment: I know the answers for all different processes should be the same. This is reason I want to know what logical error I made in my code?

Comment: you misread Victor's comment: all your MPI ranks compute the same value.

Comment: How can I divide the main problem into sub problems?

Comment: start with `n=1` and `p=2`, how would you do that (in plain English)?

Comment: n/p .  In code `local_n= n/comm_sz;`

Comment: let me try this way then: look at the initial formula. Can you identify a domain that can be split into subdomains?

Comment: for loop.   `for (i =0;i <= n;i++) {
cal_sum = cal_sum + 4*(pow (-1, i))/((2*i)+1);
}`

Comment: there is definitely a domain here! can you identify it? any idea how to decompose/split it?

Comment: No I did not identify the domain.

Comment: I will leave you with that: describe in plain English how you would compute the serie with `n=1` and `p=2`. Keep it simple by considering how to parallelize this loop on two tasks: `for(i=0; i<=1; i++) { cal_sum = cal_sum + f(i); }

Comment: local_n= n/comm_sz; for (local_i =0;local_i <= local_n;local_i++) {
local_sum = local_sum + 4*(pow (-1, i))/((2*i)+1);
}

Comment: so let's assume that was plain English. What is `local_sum` value on task `0`? on task `1`? do they add up to `2.667` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is `logical error` in your code.

Scenario 1:
When `comm_sz` = 1;

```
For the iteration i = 0 : n=1, so loop condition 0<=1 is true
Value of cal_sum will be 4

For the iteration i = 0 : n=1, so loop condition 1<=1 is true
Value of cal_sum will be 4 + - (4/3) =  2.667
```

Scenario 2:
When `comm_sz` = 2;

In `my_rank = 0`;

```
For the iteration i = 0 : n=0.5, so loop condition 0<=0 is true
So Value of cal_sum will be 4;
For the iteration i = 1 : n=0.5, so loop condition is false
exits the loop with cal_sum as 4;
```

In `my_rank = 1`;

```
For the iteration i = 0 : n=0.5, so loop condition 0<=0 is true
So Value of cal_sum will be 4;

For the iteration i = 1 : n=0.5, so loop condition is false
exits the loop with cal_sum as 4;
```

Hence the resulting value is `comm_sz * 4 = 8`.

Basically, the same thing happens, even if you have 8 processes, the sum will be 32.

The result from your code will always be `comm_sz*4` if `comm_sz > 1`.

I hope this will assist you to understand the issue in your code.

You should also consider how to distribute the tasks across different processes.

**Hint**: Say if you have `comm_size=4` and `n=8`, the `local_sum` for each process should calculate `n/comm_size` iterations but with different **starting and ending indexes**. i.e `rank 0` should calculate sum for `i=0 to 1`, `rank 1` for `i=2 to i=3` ...  `rank 4` should calculate `i=6 to i=8`.

Comment: As long as I understand from your comment that the problem arises because n=0.5 is a floating point number. So, if I write down local_n = ceil(n/comm_sz) does this improve the situation? In hint section how could I define stating and ending index and varying i? If you write down that portion code snippet that would be great help

Comment: celi did not help. If p=2 I got 8.00 as answer even if I used celi. I did the math manually, if i is 0,1,2 means n=2 the answer should be 52/15. I think the summation formula stands for integer number. So how could I handle floating point number?

Comment: Do you need to handle floating point numbers? value of `i=0` to `n` is `integer` in the formula right? If `n =1`, then you only need to use `1` or maybe `2` process. if `n>num_procs`, then divide the `n` equally(if possible) among all processes.

Comment: how can I implement the hint portion that you have given in your answer?

Comment: @Encipher It might look like this (I didn't test it on system). You only need to change the for loop Inside `sum()` like this `for ( i=my_rank*local_n;i < (my_rank+1)*local_n; i++)`.  Make sure that the last rank will execute till `i <= (my_rank+1)*local_n;` inside the for loop i.e last rank should do one more iteration than all the other processes. This is just a naive way. You could always come up with elegant and optimised solutions :)